# Finding triangle side length as a circle inside moves

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

Sorry for the bad title, I have no idea how to describe my issue in a line.

As you can see in the simple diagram I made, I have a "ball" (circle) inside an isosceles triangle. I need my triangle to always "squeeze" (touch) the circle as it moves up and down. So as it moves up, the triangle gets smaller, and vice versa. I know the height of the triangle, the radius of the ball, and the height of the ball within the triangle. I just need to know how I can calculate the top side of the triangle to adjust it's width so it's touching the circle when I move it.

[image]

Comment: How is it related to C#? You don't mention anything C#-specific in your question.

Comment: Looks like a math question instead of programming question

Comment: This is definitely a maths question and not a programming one. Note that if you take a diameter of the circle parallel to the line whose length you want to find, that forms the base of a smaller isosceles triangle whose height (per your diagram) is 4 units. You should be able to calculate the angle of the bottom point of the triangle and then use that to calculate the side you want.

Comment: You'd better ask math questions on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a math problem within my c# project, but explained it as solely a math problem. Should have given some c# notes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let units center of circle is from bottom = h and w be the width to calculate.
w = 40 / (h^2-4)^1/2

With radius of 2, half the bottom angle = sin-1 (2/h) which is also = tan-1 (w/2 / 10)
Taking tan of both sides and squaring, simplifying ... solving for w:
2/h / (1 - (2/h)^2)^1/2 = w/2 / 10

w = 40 / (h^2 - 4)^1/2

In c#:

```
    // given height from bottom 'h' and assuming 2 < h <= 8
    public double GetWidth(double h)
    {
        return (40 / Math.Pow((Math.Pow(h, 2) - 4), 0.5));
    }
```

Comment: That's awesome! :) Quick question, though (and this is just an extra, so don't feel like you need to answer this...) Is there a way to create that formula, but with the height of the triangle (10), being a variable that can change as you move the circle? It'll never be smaller than the circle of course.

Comment: Letting `l` be the full length of the height instead of constant `10`. You would have an equation for `w` with two variables. - i.e., `w = 4l / (h^2 - 4)^1/2`

Comment: And in other words, if I understand your question -- you want the height of the triangle to be the bottom to the center of the circle? ... if so, you would have `h` equal `l`. so `w = 4h / (h^2 - 4)^1/2`